# 379 CLR threads are waiting in the hang dump

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windbg, crash-dumps

On one env we have some sort of hang when application stop working as it should. I have a dump and when I open it in VS I see that I have 379 threads.

When I see the call stacks of that threads I see somethink like

```
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa C/C++/ASM
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x92   C/C++/ASM
clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x38    C/C++/ASM
clr!CLREventWaitHelper+0x1f C/C++/ASM
clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x70   C/C++/ASM
clr!AppDomain::ADUnloadThreadStart+0x190    C/C++/ASM
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d C/C++/ASM
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x1a   C/C++/ASM
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d   C/C++/ASM
```

All that threads are normal priority and threre are some high priority with call stack like

```
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa  C/C++/ASM
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xe5    C/C++/ASM
clr!SVR::WaitForFinalizerEvent+0xb7 C/C++/ASM
clr!SVR::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+0x4a C/C++/ASM
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x2d    C/C++/ASM
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x6c   C/C++/ASM
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x75    C/C++/ASM
clr!SVR::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+0xd7  C/C++/ASM
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d C/C++/ASM
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x1a   C/C++/ASM
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d   C/C++/ASM
```

I have litle expirience in dump analysys. Can you explaine what is all about?
It looks like that threads are waiting for some event. But what event and why so much threads?

Comment: Just from initial glance, I noticed `GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart`, looks like you could have garbage collection running.

Comment: Do you have any code in a Dispose method anywhere that could take a while to run, such as a Database calls?

Comment: @BradleyUffner That is huge project with a lot of finalizations of native resources. But it is well tested. Looks like that issue occur under the stress. That env. is highly loaded. I see what you mean... finalization hang.. mb

Comment: It could be a race condition or deadlock in a finalizer if it only happens under heavy load.  It doesn't sound fun to track down.

Comment: The bottom trace is entirely normal, the finalizer thread waiting for any work to do.  The top one is not normal, the CLR started a thread to unload an AppDomain but there are other thread(s) executing in the AppDomain that are not in an alertable wait-state so can't be aborted.  Just don't wait too long before making the minidump.

Comment: the top stack is normal. the ADUnloadThreadStart thread is there but waiting. it's not doing anything. it's common to have this thread on ASP.NET apps